# Azure CosmosDb Emulator not starting

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I uninstalled and re-installed the Azure CosmosDB emulator on my PC, but cannot start it up now.  I keep getting the following error:

```
Failed creating emulator certificate. Error: 0x8009000f
```

I have run through all of the steps in the trouble shooting guide but I am still experiencing the problem. Has anyone experienced this too and if so, how did you manage to resolve it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [`Docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#export-the-ssl-certificate)

> In order to obtain a certificate to use with languages and runtimes
>   that do not integrate with the Windows Certificate Store you will need
>   to export it using the Windows Certificate Manager.

Also when you are running try to use **`https`**